# VB.Net - Populating a listbox via a text file, but the program should create the file first

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I wasn't sure how to word this title, it's sort of a weird question. I created a program that will do a few things. It will create a new text file, output two separate pieces of data on a button click, and then populates a listbox with state names and senator information. Here's my code:

```
Public Class SenNumbers

Dim Senate113 As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Senate113.txt")
Dim RetiredSen As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("RetiredSen.txt")
Dim NewSen As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("NewSen.txt")

Dim Remaining() As String = (Senate113.Except(RetiredSen)).ToArray

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Senate114.txt", Remaining.Union(NewSen))
    txtFile.Text = "The file has been successfully created."

End Sub

Private Sub btnCount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCount.Click

    Dim democrats As Integer
    Dim republicans As Integer
    Dim independents As Integer

    Dim query = From Senator In Remaining
                Let affiliation = Senator.Split(","c)(2)
                Select affiliation

    For i As Integer = 0 To query.Count - 1
        If query(i) = "D" Then
            democrats += 1
        ElseIf query(i) = "R" Then
            republicans += 1
        ElseIf query(i) = "I" Then
            independents += 1
        End If
        txtDemo.Text = democrats
        txtRepub.Text = republicans
        txtInd.Text = independents
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btnSameAffil_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSameAffil.Click


    Dim sameParty As Integer

    Dim query = From Senator In Remaining
                Let state = Senator.Split(","c)(1)
                Let affiliation = Senator.Split(","c)(2)
                Order By state Ascending
                Select affiliation

    For i As Integer = 0 To query.Count - 2 Step 2
        If query(i) = query(i + 1) Then
            sameParty += 1
        End If
        txtSameAffil.Text = sameParty
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub SenNumbers_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim query = From State In Remaining
                Let States As String = State.Split(","c)(1)
                Order By States
                Select States
                Distinct

    lstStates.DataSource = query.ToList

End Sub

Private Sub lstStates_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstStates.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim currentState = lstStates.Text

    Dim query = From values In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Senate114.txt")
                Let senator = values.Split(","c)(0)
                Let state = values.Split(","c)(1)
                Where state = currentState
                Select senator

    lstSenators.DataSource = query.ToList

End Sub

End Class
```

But my specific issue comes from the final event handler, this block of code:

```
Private Sub lstStates_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstStates.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim currentState = lstStates.Text

Dim query = From values In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Senate114.txt")
            Let senator = values.Split(","c)(0)
            Let state = values.Split(","c)(1)
            Where state = currentState
            Select senator

lstSenators.DataSource = query.ToList

End Sub
```

The intention of this program is for the user to first click a button that will create the Senator114.txt file. Therefore, the file shouldn't be pre-loaded. However, the listbox uses that file itself to populate the data. So if the file isn't loaded, the program obviously doesn't run.

I've considered two methods around this.

1) Manually populating the listboxes (obviously inefficient)

2) Creating a button so the listboxes don't populate until I've clicked that button.

Are these basically my only options? I don't think there's any way to delay the listbox from populating until I click my create button to make the file, is there?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168053/my-chats)

Comment: I don't really understand the issue you're having... You are loading the `Senator114.txt` file when you select a state. So if you need it to be created without having the user press a button, can't you just create it in the [**`Form.Load` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Hey @VisualVincent, thanks for your reply :) The instructions for the program explicitly state that the user needs to press a button to create the file. The listbox uses that created file to populate. So basically the form loads and the listbox needs the file, but the file isn't there because it hasn't yet been created. And you can't create the file because the error from the listbox disallows the form to load.

Comment: Ah, that was the specific piece of information that was missing from your question: what was actually happening when you ran the code. It's vital that you provide a full and clear explanation of the problem, otherwise it gets very hard to diagnose and will most likely end up in guesswork. It usually doesn't have to be any more complicated than saying _"X happens when I do Y"_.

Comment: You're awesome @VisualVincent - that's EXACTLY what I needed, and I managed to get the form to run properly with some minor changes. I apologize for not being specific enough, didn't even realize I wasn't until you pointed that out :) Thank you greatly!

Comment: No problem. Just choose to accept the duplicate so that this question gets closed (should be a notification in the top of your question).